# I can't delete files like "#test.cpp#~" in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm using Ubuntu linux. I have a file `#test.cpp#~` and when I try to run the following command in the terminal:

```
rm #test.cpp#~
```

all I get is:

```
rm: missing operand
```

Can someone tell me what's happening? I think the file is an autosave but I don't know how to delete it.

Comment: Thanks Burhan Khalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` and `#` have special meaning in shell environment. User quotes:

```
rm "#test.cpp#~"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the # try the following:

```
rm \#test.cpp\#~
```

you may need to do

```
rm \#test.cpp\#\~
```